# Why synchronize keyword in java is not working without join()

Tags: java, multithreading

The below code is not giving the result of the counter=200 if I comment t1.join,t2.join here what I am assuming is that we have synchronized keyword to the increment() method that would let one thread to allow into increment() method,  let's say t1 is allowed then t1 makes counter to 100 then t1 is done then t2 would get a lock and  take the already updated counter value of 100 then start incrementing from 101 to 200 but if I comment join methods then the program is not working as
expected

I would really appreciate your time to help me to understand this

```
public class InterthreadExp1 {

    private static int counter =0;

    public static synchronized void increment() {
        counter++;
    }

    public static void process() {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    increment();
                }

            }
        });


        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    increment();
                }

            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        
        /*
         * try { t1.join(); t2.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         * e.printStackTrace(); }
         */
         
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process();
        System.out.println("Couter value "+counter);

    }

}
```

Comment: where is synchronized?

Comment: You have no `synchronized` method/block in your code.

Comment: Must be a reason why `synchronized` is not working ;)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add. now I have added

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluP You want to print the result when both threads are complete. So, change `t1.start(); t2.start()` to `t1.start();  t2.start(); t1.join(); t2.join();`.

Comment: If you don't join, the main method will have finished before the threads have had a chance to run. Starting a thread takes time, and in the mean time, the main-thread just continues. As an aside, `counter` needs to be marked volatile, or you need to get its current value in a synchronized block as well, otherwise the main-thread is not guaranteed to see the most recent value (though a thread `join()` would establish a happens-before relationship).

Answer (score 0):

Here If we comment out t1.join and t2.join methods then the t1 thread Or t2 thread starts and executes the increment method at the same time main thread also prints the counter value  before finishing the operation of t1 or t2

if we uncomment join statements then the main method would wait till the time t1 and t2 threads are done then only the main thread would print counter value that would give us expected results